# Relocation out of range; R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21; Variable via Linker script;

Tags: linker, arm, arm64, linker-scripts

I got an linker relocation error

```
relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 out of range: 8556371968 is not in [-4294967296, 4294967295]
```

There is a code which uses this relocated symbol (simplified, not actual but enough to get an idea)

```
extern "C" extern void* memOffset; 

void* getAddress(const void* addr)
{
  return (void*)((uintptr_t)addr + (uintptr_t)&memOffset);
}
```

`memOffset` is provided via a Linker script and calculated as: `memOffset = addr1 - addr2;`

Well, when addresses difference is over 32b there is a relocation error.

Is there a way to provide this full scale 64b 'offset' variable like a linker script symbol?

Thanks

PS: I'm interesting in keeping one symbol 'offset', not workaround like passing addresses (`addr1` & `addr2`) in code and calculate addresses offset at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need -fPIC compilation option, while compiling your .c file(s).

Answer (score 0):

if you're attempting to cross compile a lib with precompiled `.a` or `.so.x` files, gcc might be attempting to use the static version of the library because it can find the `.so` file.

A simple `ln -s libX.so.1.2.3 libX.so` might fix this for you.